# Make symbols loaded on the preemptive link show up in the front-end

Tags: front-end

I have a stylesheet with a button that will load the current package I'm developing, which it just does via [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html). When I use this though the symbol contexts aren't updated in the front-end. I need to evaluate something in a cell before that happens. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @Kuba definitely is. I searched for a bit but didn't find a previous answer.

Comment: The only way I find duplicates is when I know the answer :P so "is:a isaccepted:yes GetUpdatedSymbolContexts" etc :)

Comment: @Kuba I'm 100% fine with closing it. I just know I searched for this sort of thing ~6 months back and couldn't find it, so I thought I'd put it here.

Comment: Yep, not easy to find if you don't know the name of the function so good to have another road sign.

Answer (score 1):

All we need is to use `` FrontEnd`Private`GetUpdatedSymbolContexts ``

See here:

[image: no update]
[image: update]